# Revoked Puppet certs active after puppet clean

Tags: puppet

I revoke the certificate of a node in puppet:

```
puppet revoke node1.example.com
```

The certificate is revoked as expected.

```
- "node1.example.com"    (SHA1) 05:88:D6:73:C0:35:3C:25:89:0C:7E:CE:DC:A6:39:76:13:C4:46:C3 (certificate revoked)
```

After running:

```
puppet cert clean node2.example.com
```

The certificate of node2 is revoked and removed correctly, but the certificate of node1 is active again.

```
+ "node1.example.com"    (SHA1) 05:88:D6:73:C0:35:3C:25:89:0C:7E:CE:DC:A6:39:76:13:C4:46:C3
```

Is this a bug or a feature?

Puppet version is 3.7.3

Comment: Try monitoring the content of your CRL with `openssl`.

Answer (score 0):

Is your node still trying to run puppet? If you remove the node and node connects to puppet, it might generate again a new certificate.

I would suggest to remove the certificate and run puppet on your node1 with debug mode, to see what happens.

It will mention the missing certificate, and how your client reacts on this.

If you do not want this node to be able to connect, then just revoke it.

If this is not the case, you should clean the certificate from the puppet master folder and restart puppet master. (might be a bug)

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same issue. I revoke a host cert:
puppet cert --revoke host1.example.com

I verify that the host1 cert was added to the crl, restarted puppetmaster and the client is indeed banned.

I clean another's host cert:
puppet cert --clean host2.example.com

I verify that host1 cert was REMOVED from crl and host2 cert was added to it.

Now host1 can run puppet and host2 cannot.